# Can't get cache manifest to work MIME type problem

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to get my website to use the cache manifest properly.

The steps i've taken:

```
<html lang="en" manifest="/iphone.manifest"> this is in the one and only html file
```

Below is saved as iphone.manifest:
    CACHE MANIFEST

```
CACHE:
/index.html
/css/main.css
/images/icon.png
/images/icon4.png
/images/splash.png
/images/loading.gif
/images/test.jpg

# version 0
```

and i added the line: text/cache-manifest .manifest
to the mime.types file of my xampp server

The server still seems to be using text/plain

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding some more dummy MIME mappings such as `text/html .cat`, `text/html .dog` and `text/html .mouse` and try adding `iphone.cat`, `iphone.dog` and `iphone.mouse` files to your server and accessing them. If they are sent as `text/plain` also then it looks like the mappings aren't being picked up if `text/plain` is the default.

Comment: On second thoughts, if the config is like this - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipapachexhtml/index.html - then are you sure you need the period before the extension?

Comment: Good catch on the .manifest minus the "."!  Unfortunately, it still doesn't work even after i changed that.  I'll try the cat dog thing next.

Comment: Clear browser cache? Maybe your change worked but the browser has still cached the old manifest? Or if you have the ability to run PHP files or similar then change the manifest to iphone.manifest.php and include PHP statements in the file to force the content type.